# Selenium IDE extension or plugin for regex changes

Tags: java, regex, webdriver, add-in, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE right now, everything is working fine, but I want to modify generated code automatically after it's copied from Selenium IDE. Modifications should be made based on regular expressions.

I managed to develop a tool in java that operates on clipboard data. However now I need it's functionality integrated with Selenium IDE, not as another tool run from cmd.

Is there a Selenium IDE API method, that would allow me to operate on data before being copied from SeIDE? I need it only for Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver..

--edit--

any other option, that would let me automate it (even with my current java tool) would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the IDE, but I'm betting the code is in a file somewhere that sed could get to it and run regex expressions on it. Check out  http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction

Comment: Hmm...first of all (I forgot to mention it), I'm working on Windows (requirement). And another thing - running regex should not be as big problem as automating it's run with Selenium. But still thanks for help :)